# Rhino Security , getting all usergroups

Tags: nhibernate, rhino, rhino-security

I am using ayende's Rhino Security . Is there any method to get a list of usergroups using the security framework ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, but you can do `session.CreateCriteria<UserGroup>().List<UserGroup>();`